# How is $\Pr(X > 0)= \mathbb{E}[XY]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}$, where each $X_i$ is $0$-$1$ random variable.

The prove starts with

> Let $Y=1/X$ if $X>0$, with $Y=0$ otherwise. Then $$\Pr(X >0) = \mathbb{E}[XY] $$

I understand that $$\Pr(X>0)= \Pr(X=1) + \dots + \Pr(X=n)$$ and 
$$ \mathbb{E}[XY] = \sum{(xy)\Pr(x,y)}$$
but cannot prove these quantities are equal. Could someone give me a hint?

---

Reference: *Probability and Computing* by M.Mitzenmacher & E.Upfal, pg 137.

Comment: What is the value of $XY$ when $X=0$? When $X > 0$?

Comment: Use chain rule of expectations. $E[XY] = E_X [E_{Y|X}[Y|X]]$. The inner part is a constant function of $X$. The outer will be involving only $pr(X)$, not $pr(XY)$. I think that simplifies things a bit.

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo, if $X=0$ then $xY = 0Y = 0$ for any $y$. But when $X>0$, then $xY = c\times 1/d$ for some $c$ and $d$ for $c,d < n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the piecewise definition of $Y$,
$$XY=\begin{cases}X\cdot(1/X)&\text{if }X>0\\X\cdot(0) & \text{if }X=0\end{cases}=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }X>0\\0 & \text{if }X=0\end{cases}$$
So $XY$ takes on two values; it equals $1$ with probability $P(X>0$), and it equals $0$ with probability $P(X=0)$. Therefore,
$$
E[XY]=1\cdot P(XY=1)+0\cdot P(XY=0)=1\cdot P(X>0)+0\cdot P(X=0)=P(X>0).
$$

Comment: My source of confusion is that I thought $XY$ takes all possible values $xy$, where $x =0,1\dots, n$, and $y=0,1, 1/2, \dots, 1/n$, while you claim that $XY$ takes only two values $0$ and $1$. Isn't $Y$ a r.v. on its own, which takes values: $0,1, 1/2, \dots 1/n$? And so $XY$ may take $3\times 1/7$ for example.

Comment: You would be correct if $X$ and $Y$ are _independent_. In this case, $Y$ is determined by $X$, so you cannot have (say) $X=2$ and $Y=1/3$. The only cases are $(X,Y)=(0,0),(1,1),(2,1/2),(3,1/3),\dots,(n,1/n)$, and in all cases (except the first), you have $XY=1$.

Comment: So, when we write $Y=1/X$ it is not clear, at least to me, if $X$ and $Y$ are dependent or not. We could interpret $Y = 1/X$ simply as "$Y$'s values are generated by dividing $1$ by values taken by $X$. Couldn't we? I found simply stating $Y=1/X$ a bit confusing.

Comment: @B.K. People will **never** use the equation $Y=1/X$ to mean "Y is independent of X, but takes the same values as 1/X". The equation $Y=1/X$ always refers to the situation described in my comment. This is an important point (and common source of confusion).